# Should we use the topmost parent class as a type of reference variable?

Tags: java, performance, collections

I have seen some people using the topmost parent class as a variable type to hold the child instance and some people use just parent class only. For example:

```
Collection obj = new ArrayList();
Or
List obj = new ArrayList();
```

Here, List comes under the Collection only then can’t we use above first line instead of second?

Again, we can't use everywhere in collection framework the reference variable of Collection class only to hold any instance of the class under Collection?

Is this a good practice?

So, I wanted to know which comes under the best practices and why?

If someone could justify technically like performance concerns etc. would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general idea is hiding as much as you can so things are easier to change. If you need indexing for instance (List.get(int index) then it MUST be a list because a collection does not support .get(index). If you don't need indexing, then hiding the fact you're using a list, means you can switch to other collections that might not be a list later without any trouble.

For example, maybe one month later I want to use a set instead of list. But Set doesn't support .get(index). So anybody who uses this List might use the indexing features of a list and it would make it difficult to switch to a set because every where someone else used .get(), would break.

On the other hand, excessively hiding your types can cause accidental performance issues because a consumer of your method didn't know the type. Suppose you return a List that's actually a linkedlist (where indexing is O(n)). Suppose the consumer of this list does a lookup for each entry in another list. That can be O(n*m) performance which is really slow. If you advertised that it was a linked list in the first place, the consumer of the linkedlist would realize that it's probably not a good idea to make multiple indexes into this list and the consumer can make a local copy.

Library code (suppose the one you're designing)

```
public class Util {
  public static List<String> makeData() {
    return new LinkedList(Arrays.asList("dogs", "cats", "zebras", "deer"));
  }
}
```

Caller's code (suppose the one that's using your library or method)

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
  List<String> data = Util.makeData();
  int [] indicesToLookUp = {1,4,2,3,0};
  for( int idx : indicesToLookUp ) {
    if(idx < data.size()) { 
      // each index (LinkedList.get()) is slow O(N)
      doSomethingWithEntry(idx, list.get(idx)); 
    }
  }
}
```

You could argue it's the caller's fault because he incorrectly assumed the List is an ArrayList<> and should have made a local copy of the list.

Comment: This can be a good answer so, I'll give you one vote up. but I couldn't understand the meaning of last para where you have mentioned "That can be O(n*m) performance which is really slow.". Could you please give me some good references on it to understand it in better way?

Comment: I don't have a reference for it as that's an anecdote from my development. I'll try to add an example. I do have more on the first two paragraphs here: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/132019/what-is-the-value-in-hiding-the-details-through-abstractions-isnt-there-value . They do a MUCH better job than I did.

Answer (score 3):

There is no so called "best practice" for choosing the class to be used for the reference type. In fact, the class in the highest hierarchy is the Object class. Do you use Object as the reference type for everything you do? No, but generally you may choose the higher class with the all the methods available for your needs.

Instead of following the so called "best practice", apply what suits best for your situation.

These are some pros and cons for using higher hierarchy classes as reference type:

**Advantage**

- Allows grouping of object which shares the same ancestor (super class)
- Allows all instances of the given class to be assigned to it

  ```
  Animal dog = new Dog(); 
  Animal cat = new Cat();
  ```
- Allows polymorphism

  ```
  dog.makeNoise();
  cat.makeNoise();
  ```

It is only an advantage when you are accessing **common** behaviours or members.

**Disadvantage**

- Requires casting when you are accessing behaviours which exist in one object but not the other.

  ```
  dog.swim();  //error, class Animal do not have swim()
  ((Dog)dog).swim();
  ```
- As you start dumping various objects in the common parent class, you may have a hard time trying to figure out which members belongs to which class.

  ```
  (Cat(cat)).swim();  //error, class Cat do not have swim()
  ```

Answer (score 2):

It really really depends on your needs. In your example it doesn't really changes much for basic needs but if you inspect the two interfaces there are some changes. Look : 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html 
and
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html

We can notice that the List gives you access to methods Collection doesn't.
set(int index, E element) for instance is defined in the List interface and not in Collection.

This is because every classes inheriting from Collection don't need to implement all the same methods.

Performance wise it have no impact.

Always use the top-most parent class that have all the functionalities you need. For your example there is no need to go higher than List .